An internal error occurred during: "Building UI model". Could not initialize class sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext
I am getting this error while creating new spring boot application in sts 4.22.0 with java openjdk version "17.0.10" 2024-01-16 LTS install on windows 11
can anyone please help me on this. unable to make progress on spring boot project.
STS error
JDK version
this is the similar question for eclipse
An internal error occurred during: "Building UI model"
I have tried to change java version 8 and 11, also changed the network connection active provider to Direct, Native and Manual.
